# Using an inequality operator to compare objects

Tags: ios, equality

Using != here seems wrong to me. We are comparing objects so isEqual should be the correct approach ?

Unless NSNull null returns a singleton with a consistent memory address ?

```
if ([super actionForLayer:layer forKey:@"backgroundColor"] != [NSNull null]) {
// whatever
}
```

Nick Lockwood is using this in his gist [here](https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/d374033b27c62662ac8d) It's a cool read btw

Comment: [NSNull null] always returns a singleton with a consistent memory address, so the equality check is correct in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

== operator check that whether two pointers pointing the same objects or not whereas `isEqual` checks whether the content of the objects are same or  not but the two object pointers may not be pointing to same address.

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
NSString *s2 = s1;
NSString *s3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];

if (s1 == s2)
    NSLog(@"result 1");

if (s2 == s3)
    NSLog(@"result 2");

if ([s1 isEqual:s2])
    NSLog(@"result 3");

if ([s2 isEqual:s3])
    NSLog(@"result 4");

if (!([s2 isEqual:s3])) //Not equal for objects (change value to see)
    NSLog(@"result 5");

//prints pointer addresses
NSLog(@"%p", s1);
NSLog(@"%p", s2);
NSLog(@"%p", s3);
```

Answer (score -2):

Unless isEqual is overriden in the class, there is no difference between == and isEqual.